# PayPal Delayed Payment - Until Package Delievered

Tags: paypal

Just looking for some advice about the paypal delayed payment feature...

Basically i'm in the process of setting up a marketing place and I'm just wondering is it possible for the buyer to pay for the goods using paypal but for the money to only go thorugh when the package has been delivered?

I don't want to delay it bay 90 days I want control over when the payment is made...

Is this possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Paypal policies and capabilities, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Delayed Chained Payment Using Adaptive Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/), what you want is to ExecutePayment after you make sure the package is shipped/delivered.

Hope this helps.